# How should I prove the duality?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Rudin asked (*Real Complex Analysis, First edition, Chapter 6, Problem 4*):

Suppose $1\le p\le \infty$, and $q$ is the exponent conjugate to $p$. Suppose $u$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure and $g$ is a measurable function such that $fg\in L^{1}(\mu)$ for every $f\in L^{p}(\mu)$. Prove that then $g\in L^{q}(\mu)$.

I am being troubled with the fact that $|g|_{q}$ might be unbounded if we select wierd enough $f$. Holder inequality only gives us $$|fg|_{1}\le |f|_{p}|g|_{q}\leftrightarrow |g|_{q}\ge \frac{|fg|_{1}}{|f|_{p}}$$All  the constructions I know proving $g\in L^{q}$ starts by assuming $f\rightarrow fg$ is a bounded linear operator，so I cannot use circular reasoning at here.

It suffice to prove the statement for finite measure spaces and simple functions. So emulating Rudin we can assume $|g|=\alpha g$, where $|\alpha|=1$ and $\alpha$ is measurable. Let $E_{n}=x:|g(x)|\le n$ and let $f=\chi_{E_{n}}\alpha g^{q-1}$. Then we have $$\int_{E_{n}}|g|^{q}d\mu=\int_{X}|fg|d\mu\le K_{n}$$ for some $K_{n}<\infty$. But this constant obviously shift with the $n$ I choose, hence probably does not have a finite upper bound (for example $K_{n}=n$). And I got stuck.

In problem 6, Rudin now ask:

Suppose $1<p<\infty$, and prove that $L^{q}(\mu)$ is the dual space of $L^{p}(\mu)$ even if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

I keep thinking about it but do not know what is the best way to prove it.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61458/if-f-is-measurable-and-fg-is-in-l1-for-all-g-in-lq-must-f-in-lp) post.

Comment: I am curious where the proof broke for the $p=1,\infty$ when it is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: For $p=1,\infty$ necessary and sufficient conditions and a counterexample when they fail are given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150547/).

Comment: I see. Now everything is pieced together. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidMitra: I am wondering what can I do to prove this without $\sigma$-finite assumption in $1<p<\infty$ case. The approach I know only works with $\sigma$-finite hypothesis.

Comment: I see. I need to use the one for Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I don't think the case where the measure is not $\sigma$-finite is so easy. The proofs I've seen use the fact that for $1<p<\infty$, $L_p$ is uniformly convex. One proof using this approach can be found on page 330 of [these](http://elibrary.bsu.az/azad/s1_kitab/749.PDF) notes (which uses Clarkson's inequality to show $L_p$ is uniformly convex for $2\le p<\infty$. Another proof (also using Clarkson's inequality) can be found in Hewitt and Stromberg's *Real and Abstract Analysis*.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes, that's why I asked. I do not think Rudin will assume I know uniform convex or Clarkson's inequality, and he did not introduce Riesz representaion theorem for Hilbert space in that chapter. So he must have imagined some different proof.

Comment: @DavidMitra: A look on the definition of uniformly convex space looked very familiar; I might have proved this before. So maybe this is Rudin's strategy. Thanks.

Comment: @David: You can reduce to the $\sigma$-finite case. That the map $L^q \to (L^p)^\ast$ is isometric is easy, so surjectivity is at stake. The idea is that a functional $\varphi$ on $L^p$ must be "supported" on a $\sigma$-finite set: if $f_n \in L_p$ are normalized functions such that $\varphi(f_n) \to \lVert \varphi\rVert$ then the set $E_n = \{x : \sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(x)|^p \geq 2^{-n}\}$ has finite measure and one shows that $\varphi$ cannot charge functions with support entirely outside $E = \bigcup E_n$. Now localize to $E$ and apply the argument from the $\sigma$-finite case.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is about the last part on how to extend the duality beyond $\sigma$-finite measures since the first part is taken care of in [If $f$ is measurable and $fg$ is in $L^1$ for all $g \in L^q$, must $f \in L^p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61458/if-f-is-measurable-and-fg-is-in-l1-for-all-g-in-lq-must-f-in-lp) mentioned by David Mitra.

---

The answer to "what is the best way to prove that $L^{q}(\mu)$ is the dual space of $L^{p}(\mu)$ even if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite" is probably a matter of taste. I think the proof using uniform convexity and the Milman-Pettis theorem suggested by David Mitra is nice. The usual expositions apply [Clarkson's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson's_inequalities) or [Hanner's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanner's_inequalities). The latter are easier to prove than the former, but they leave me with the feeling of coming out of the blue, see also [the discussion on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27691/).

An illuminating discussion of the approach to duality via uniform convexity of the $L^p$-spaces is given by Harald Hanche-Olsen, [On the uniform convexity of $L^p$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-06-08366-3), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 134 (2006), 2359-2362. The paper ends with an outline of the proof you're asking about. Alternatively, you can consult the references provided by David Mitra in the comments.

---

However, I doubt that the above-mentioned proofs are what Rudin had in mind in this exercise. After all, we want to prove that $L^q$ is dual to $L^p$ for $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ by using the methods he provides in said chapter and by reducing to the $\sigma$-finite case.

It is not hard to prove that the natural map $L^q \to (L^p)^\ast$ given by sending $g \in L^q$ to $\varphi_g(f) = \int f g$ is isometric: this uses Hölder's inequality and one verifies that $f = \lVert g\rVert_{p}^{1-p} \frac{\lvert g\rvert}{g}$ is an $L^p$ function of norm $\lVert f \rVert_q = 1$ such that $\varphi_g(f) = \lVert g\rVert_q$.

It remains to prove that every $\varphi \in (L^p)^\ast$ is of the form $\varphi_g$ for some $g \in L^q$.

Observe that a function $g \in L^q$ must vanish outside of a set of $\sigma$-finite measure (since $\lvert g\rvert^q$ is integrable). So, given a continuous functional $\varphi \colon L^p \to \mathbb{R}$, we must somehow be able to prove that it is "supported" on a set of $\sigma$-finite measure. By this I mean that we must be able to find a $\sigma$-finite set $E$ such that $f|_E = 0$ implies $\varphi(f) = 0$. If we have that, the known duality applies.

Let $f_n \in L^p$ be functions of norm $\lVert f_n\rVert_p = 1$ such that $\varphi(f_n) \to \lVert \varphi \rVert$. The intuition is that $\lVert \varphi\rVert-\varepsilon \lt \varphi(f_n) \leq \lVert \varphi\rVert$ means that $\varphi$ must almost be zero on functions whose support is disjoint from the one of $f_n$.

Collect all the supports of the $f_n$'s together into one set $E$, using a small trick to show that it is $\sigma$-finite: let $E_n = \{x \in X : \sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(x)|^p \geq 2^{-n}\}$. We have $\mu(E_n) \lt \infty$ and $E = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ is a set of $\sigma$-finite measure containing the  supports of all the $f_n$'s. If we manage to prove that $\varphi(h) = 0$ for all $h \in L^p$ such that $h|_E = 0$ we're done: $E$ is $\sigma$-finite and thus we find a function $g$ in $L^q(E)$ representing $\varphi$ (extend $g$ by zero on $X \setminus E$).

Notice that $L^p(X) = L^p(E) \mathbin{\oplus_p} L^p(X \setminus E)$, by which I mean that each $f \in L^p(X)$ can be uniquely written as $f = f|_E + f|_{X \setminus E}$ and we have the identity
$$\lVert f \rVert_{p} = \left(\lVert f|_E \rVert_p^{p} + \lVert f|_{X \setminus E}\rVert_{p}^p\right)^{1/p}$$
for the norm. By duality and the assumption $1 \lt p \lt \infty$ we get
$$\lVert \varphi\rVert = \left(\lVert\varphi|_{L^p(E)}\rVert^{q} + \lVert \varphi|_{L^{q}(X\setminus E)}\rVert^q\right)^{1/q},$$
see [$(X \oplus_p Y)^*$ isometric to $(X^*\oplus_q Y^*)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236881) for details. By the choice of $E$ we have $\lVert\varphi\rVert = \lVert \varphi|_{L^p(E)}\rVert$ whence $\varphi|_{L^p(X \setminus E)} = 0$, as claimed earlier.

To repeat, $E$ is a $\sigma$-finite set, we can find $g \in L^q(E)$ such that $\varphi_g = \varphi|_{L^p(E)}$ and by setting $g = 0$ on $X \setminus E$ we get a function in $L^q(X)$ representing $\varphi$. Thus, the map $L^q(\mu) \to L^p(\mu)^\ast$ is surjective.

Comment: Give me some time to think about your solution carefully.

Comment: Sure, take all the time you need. I deliberately left some details for you to fill in. Nothing should be too hard, please don't hesitate to ask for further explanations.

Comment: Any progress? Do you need more details?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I am reading Rudin's Chapter on Differentiability theorems. Once I finished that I will read your answer carefully.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Have fun with differentiation then :-)

Comment: Sorry for being slow :(

Comment: No worries, there's no hurry! No need to feel bad at all. I only wanted to ask about the state of affairs and I didn't intend to pressure you to do anything. Go at your own pace and do whatever you are up to.

Comment: I roughly finished differentiation, though still left a lot of problems unanswered. I will spend sometime today to think about your answer carefully.

Comment: This is pretty! I really enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks! As a PS: You can see here what breaks down in the case $p=1$: it is still true that we can find such functions $f_n$ and $E$, but for the norm of $\varphi$ we only have $$\lVert \varphi \rVert = \max\{\lVert \varphi|_{L^1(E)}\rVert, \lVert \varphi|_{L^1(X \setminus E)}\rVert\}.$$ This is insufficient to conclude $\varphi|_{L^1(X \setminus E)} = 0$. We can represent the restriction $\varphi|_{L^1(E)}$ by an $L^\infty(E)$-function, but on $X \setminus E$ there is still the possibility of non-vanishing. With this approach we can try to decompose $X$ into disjoint sets ...

Comment: ... of $\sigma$-finite measure on each of which we can find an $L^\infty$-function representing $\varphi$. Then we need a further condition guaranteeing that we can "patch together" these measurable functions on these $\sigma$-finite pieces to a *measurable* function on all of $X$. It turns out that many natural measure spaces *do* have this property and, moreover, that this property --- carefully phrased --- is not only sufficient, but also *necessary* to have the duality between $L^1$ and $L^\infty$. (references in the thread linked in my first comment to your question).

Comment: Let me think about your comments carefully; I think I learned a lot today.

Comment: I have one thing to ask; how do you get $|\phi|=(|(\phi)_{E}|^{q}+|(\phi_{X/E}|^{q}|)^{1/q}$? You cited duality, but I do not see how duality in $\sigma$-finite case give me this identity. Let me think about it.

Comment: This is an abstract fact: if a Banach space $X$ can be written as $X = Y \mathbin{\oplus_p} Z$ then its dual space $X^\ast$ can be written as $X^\ast = Y^\ast \mathbin{\oplus_q} Z^\ast$. This generalizes more or less directly from the duality between the two-dimensional spaces $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lVert \cdot \rVert_p)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lVert \cdot\rVert_q)$.

Comment: I am sorry for being slow. Assume $|f|_{p}=(|f|_{E}^{p}+|f|_{X/E}^{p})^{1/p}$ and $|\phi|_{q}=\max |\phi(f)|/|f|_{p}$, then the division is complicated. Since $|f|_{X/E}^{p}=0$, this become $|\phi(f)|/)|f_{E}|_{p}=|\phi|_{E}<\infty$. But I guess that's not what you intended.

Comment: Sorry I need to sleep; but I will read your answer carefully when I woke up. Thank you.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/236881) for a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks! I feel learned a lot.