# What's so special about $p=2$ for the $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

The Banach space dual of $L^p$ is $L^q$, where $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$, but I don't really understand the motivation behind this. In particular, I find it kind of surprising that the only $L^p$ space whose dual is isomorphic $L^p$ is for $p=2$. So I guess I'm wondering what's so special about the number 2 in the context of $L^p$ spaces, or rather, where the formula $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q = 1$ originally comes from / is motivated from.

Edit: I understand that $p=2$ gives the only Hilbert space, but I'm wondering whether there's any sort of deeper reason behind the relationship between $p$ and $q$ --- does $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q = 1$ arise naturally out of integration theory in a more satisfactory way than "it just happens to be like that"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I elaborate on a remark in one of the other answers.

Consider a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ which has sets of arbitrarily small measure and sets of arbitrarily large measure. (Here I think of the Lebesgue measure on the real line.) Let $1 \leq q < \infty$ and choose

$$g \in L^q \setminus \bigcup_{p \in [1,\infty), p \neq q} L^p.$$

This is messy, but doable. [$f \in L^1$, but $f \not\in L^p$ for all $p > 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039064/f-in-l1-but-f-not-in-lp-for-all-p-1/1039097#1039097) handles the case $q=1$, and given my assumption about the measure space, you can do something similar to get higher $q$. Let $\phi(f) = \int_X fg d \mu$.

Now let us consider a function in $L^p$ which makes $\phi(f)$ "large". Specifically we take $f=|g|^{q/p} \text{sign}(g)$. The point is that this is automatically in $L^p$ since $g \in L^q$, but it is also big exactly where $g$ is big.

Now if $\frac{q}{p} + 1 = q$ then $\phi(f)=\| g \|^q_{L^q}$. Yet otherwise $\phi(f)$ is infinite! That is, $\phi$ is *only* bounded on $L^p$ if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Comment: Thanks. This, or something similar, is what I was looking for --- something that forces the Holder conjugate equation to hold.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on the standard answer ("$p=2$ is a Hilbert space and Hilbert spaces are nice"), let's talk about *why* Hilbert spaces are nice.  One of the key feature of Hilbert spaces is that they are *self dual*.  This is expressed through the [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), which says that if I want to define a bounded, linear map $\phi:L^2\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$, I just have to find the right function $g_\phi\in L^2$, and then I'll have the expression

$$
\phi(f) = \langle f,g_\phi\rangle = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} f(x)\bar{g}_\phi(x)dx
$$

The conjugate exponent expression

$$
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1 
$$

comes from wanting to compute expressions that look just like $\langle f,g\rangle$:

$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} f(x) \bar{g}(x)dx
$$

but in the case where $f\in L^p$ for any $p$, not necessarily 2!  The reason we do this is that we also want to define bounded linear maps $\phi:L^p\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$, but if $f\in L^p$, the expression

$$
\phi(f) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f(x)\bar{g}(x)dx 
$$ **will only define a bounded linear map** (i.e. the product will be an $L^1$ integrable function for *all* $f\in L^p$) when $g\in L^{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ satisfy the conjugate exponent equation.  Another way of expressing this is that the dual of $L^p$ is $L^q$, where $1/p+1/q = 1$, i.e. a version of the Riesz representation theorem holds for $L^p$, but $g_\phi\in L^q$ instead of $L^p$.

See also [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

Comment: This is not entirely true as stated. For instance if the supports of $f$ and $g$ are disjoint then $fg \in L^1$ is automatic, even if $f$ and $g$ are horrible functions.

Comment: Fair point, see edit.  The point is that the integral will not define a bounded linear functional unless $g\in L^q$.

Answer (score 2):

I think part of it is because of Holder's inequality, which dictates that
$$
|fg|_{1}\le |f|_{p}|g|_{q}
$$
But the other reasons goes into this is much deeper. For example, this duality is "structural" as it holds regardless of the measure space is $\sigma$-finite. And this has to do with concepts like uniform convexity. I used to wondering the same thing when I was learning the subject. For some related questions on this, see:

[How should I prove the duality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269402/how-should-i-prove-the-duality)

[If $f$ is measurable and $fg$ is in $L^1$ for all $g \in L^q$, must $f \in L^p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61458/if-f-is-measurable-and-fg-is-in-l1-for-all-g-in-lq-must-f-in-lp)

[If $\sum a_n b_n <\infty$ for all $(b_n)\in \ell^2$ then $(a_n) \in \ell^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/if-sum-a-n-b-n-infty-for-all-b-n-in-ell2-then-a-n-in-ell2)

[Is there a constructive proof of this characterization of $\ell^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58565/is-there-a-constructive-proof-of-this-characterization-of-ell2)

Answer (score 0):

It's the only Hilbert space. That is, the norm comes from an inner product. Hilbert spaces have a lot of nice properties. For instance they are self-dual. They have a concept of orthogonality and angle.

Comment: I see that, but I'm more curious as to how the formula $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q = 1$ might naturally arise out of integration theory, not just because "it works".